# How to output decimal numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to pull two numbers from a variable($text) and then multiply them and output the results. The two numbers can be ints and floats.

When I try:
     $text = "1 photograph - b&w - 2 x 5 in."
I get: The image area is 10
 Which is what I want

```
<?php
$text = "1 photograph - b&w - 2 x 5.5 in.";


  if (preg_match("/[[:digit:]]*\ x [[:digit:]]* /",  $text, $match)) :
   print_r($match);

    $dimensions = trim($match[0]);
    $dimensions = explode(" x ",$dimensions);
    $image_area = (($dimensions[0]) * ($dimensions[1]));



    echo 'The image area is '.($image_area);


  endif;
 ?>
```

But when I try:
     $text = "1 photograph - b&w - 2 x 5.5 in."
I get a blank screen

How would I output floats?
my code and output:http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4b45219fdcb7864442268459621bb506c24ce78f

Comment: You regex doesn't match. `' ' !== '.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space at the end of the regex, which would break it. Remove it, and it would match `2 x 5`. You should be able to extend it further by adding `\.` to each side of the regex:

```
if (preg_match("/[[:digit:]\.]*\ x [[:digit:]\.]*/",  $text, $match)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex expression isn't robust enough to distinguish between whole numbers and decimal numbers. The `[[:digit:]]` operator only matches characters 0-9.

This site is useful for creating and testing regex:

https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your regex does not match. You want:

```
/\d+(?:\.\d+)? x \d+(?:\.\d+)? /
```

1 or more digits, (optional: dot, 1 or more digits), space, x, space, 1 or more digits, (optional: dot, 1 or more digits), space

[test online](https://regex101.com/r/fwTIcb/1)